# Postgres versioned rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to keep versions in row level for Postgres

Table

```
 Column   |           Type           |            Modifiers
------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------
id         | integer                  | not null
version    | integer                  | not null default 0
Indexes:
    "mytable_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, version)
```

I am planning to use version 0 as the current version.

An example:

Initially:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, version) VALUES(1, 0);
```

Then

```
UPDATE mytable SET version = version + 1 where id = 1;
INSERT INTO mytable(id, version) VALUES(1, 0);
```

Then

```
UPDATE mytable SET version = version +1 where id = 1;
```

and got the error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (id, version)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

I am using this pattern in Mysql without problems.
Any hint of how to achieve the above in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with unique constraints in some databases.  Here is a workaround:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET version = - (version + 1)
    WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE mytable
    SET version = - version
    WHERE id = 1 AND version < 0;
```

You might also be able to fix this with `ORDER BY`:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET version = version + 1 
    WHERE id = 1
    ORDER BY version DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the unique constraint is validated "row-by-row", that's why you get that error, but you can change the constraint to be validated per statement if you defined it as deferrable:

```
alter table mytable
  add constraint pk_mytable primary key (id, version) 
  deferrable initially immediate;
```

The drawback of that solution is, that this primary key can no longer be the target of a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

what is the version of postgresql? I tested on 9.5, everything is ok.

```
    postgres=# select version();
                                                      version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# \d mytable
          Table "public.mytable"
 Column  |  Type   |     Modifiers
---------+---------+--------------------
 id      | integer | not null
 version | integer | not null default 0
Indexes:
    "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, version)

postgres=# INSERT INTO mytable(id, version) VALUES(1, 0);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# UPDATE mytable SET version = version + 1 where id = 1;
UPDATE 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO mytable(id, version) VALUES(1, 0);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# UPDATE mytable SET version = version +1 where id = 1;
UPDATE 2
postgres=# select * from mytable ;
 id | version
----+---------
  1 |       2
  1 |       1
(2 rows)
```